# Best WooCommerce hook for new order

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to execute a custom function after a user made a purchase in our WooCommerce store.

For similar cases I previously used `woocommerce_new_order`.
However if some error occurs in this custom function, this hook has the downside, that it will generate an error message visible to the user on checkout page ("something went wrong") and the user won't be forwarded to the thank you page.

I had a look at `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` however this function has the downside that it may get called twice and it can have the same error behaviour on checkout like `woocommerce_new_order`.  `woocommerce_thankyou` can also be called twice, if user reloads thank you page.

- Is there a hook that doesn't break the ordering process for user if
  an error is generated and is only called once on a new order?
- Are there performance consideration between these 3 hooks?

**My ideal hook would be:**

1. Doesn't break ordering process if an error occurs and the user/buyer lands on the thank you page no matter what.
2. Executed async from the front end order process (doesn't slow frontend down).
3. Is also called when new order is created from backend.

Comment: It is better to see what in your code is producing an error, debugging it. As you don't provide any code, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Thank you for replying @LoicTheAztec - this is a general question (without specific error / code) as to what is the best hook to use for low priority functionality to add to a new order. It's not important that the custom functionality runs succesfully but it is important that the user purchase isn't interrupted when the custom functionlity breaks.

Comment: P.s. I am currently leaning towards woocommerce_thankyou and checking if the functionality already ran (and then skipping it) via if(empty(get_post_meta( $order_id, '_checked', true ))){
  add_post_meta( $order_id, '_checked', 'checked' );
 }else{return;}

Comment: P.p.s as far as I know all 3 hooks don't fire if order is created in backend. Is there a hook that fires when order is created in backend?